# Alternative word for "reprimandable"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I couldn't find a synonym because Thesaurus doesn't offer any synonyms: http://www.thesaurus.com/misspelling?term=reprimandable.

What's another alternative of the word? Example sentence:

> The clerk sat across from Mary, a __ action if a manager saw.

Comment: http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/reprimand

Comment: Is 'reprimandable' wrong? Just because it ain't in a dictionary, don't mean it's not a legally creatable and recognizable word.

Comment: I'm confused though about the example situation. What's so wrong about sitting across from Mary that the clerk might need to be reprimanded for it? Was he manspreading?

Comment: I think *reprehensible* is the way to go. It is normally used with a slightly different connotation, but this is (very close to) its original meaning.

Comment: I concur with Jim - look up synonyms for reprimand if you can't find synonyms for reprimandable. Also I share confusion with Mitch. Is this even the right word to fill in that blank?

Comment: reproachable fits.

Comment: I small rearrangement might be necessary. Something like "The clerk sat across from Mary, risking a reprimand should a manager see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Culpable**

One would only be reprimanded if one had done something wrong. And *culpable* conveys the idea of the potential to be punished, if the wrongdoing is discovered.

> Middle English (**in the sense ‘deserving punishment’**): from Old French coupable, culpable, from Latin culpabilis, from culpare ‘to blame’, from culpa ‘fault, blame’.

[Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/culpable)